# Generate PDF file with images from mysql database

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and i have been trying to create a PDF file with images from the database.All the tutorial i have seen only put an image in the Header(not from the database) and only pull text from the database to put in the PDF.i am using FPDF to create my PDF files.Any guidelines or help to achieve this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that you have a table called `images`, where the image URLs are stored under the column `url`. You can use FPDF and the MySQL adapter to construct a PDF out of all of the images like this:

```
require 'fpdf/fpdf.php';

// DB parameters
$host = "localhost"; 
$user = "username"; 
$pass = "password";
$db = "db"; 

// Create fpdf object
$pdf = new FPDF('P', 'pt', 'Letter');

// Add a new page to the document
$pdf->addPage();

// Try to connect to DB
$r = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
if (!$r) {
    echo "Could not connect to server\n";
    trigger_error(mysql_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
} else {
    echo "Connection established\n"; 
}

// Try to select the database
$r2 = mysql_select_db($db);
if (!$r2) {
    echo "Cannot select database\n";
    trigger_error(mysql_error(), E_USER_ERROR); 
} else {
    echo "Database selected\n";
}

// Try to execute the query
$query = "SELECT * FROM images";
$rs = mysql_query($query);
if (!$rs) {
    echo "Could not execute query: $query";
    trigger_error(mysql_error(), E_USER_ERROR); 
} else {
    echo "Query: $query executed\n";
} 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
    // Get the image from each row
    $url = $row['url'];

    // Place the image in the pdf document
    $pdf->Image($url);
}

// Close the db connection
mysql_close();

// Close the document and save to the filesystem with the name images.pdf
$pdf->Output('images.pdf','F');
```

## References

- http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/how-to-create-pdf-files-with-php/
- http://zetcode.com/databases/mysqlphptutorial/

Comment: Actually i did find the right answer to my question


`$query = "SELECT imageField FROM yyy WHERE ...";   
$result = mysql_query($query);  
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);  
$image = $row['imageField'];  
$pdf->MemImage($image, 50, 30);`


But to use MemImage you have to download mem_image.php from this link  http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script45.php

Comment: what if i have many images in the database and i want to retrieve all on them because this solution is only displaying the first image i have in my table